# Spring batch trying to create existing batch tables?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

My application is using spring batch , in the first run the tables of the batch were created in the database , but in the other attempts to run it is trying to recreate the existing batch tables which causes me errors .
Is there any way to prevent spring batch from recreating these tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Batch does not create any table, you should be talking about Spring Boot. There is a way to prevent boot from creating the tables using [spring.batch.initialize-schema=never](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-spring-batch-database), but there is no way to prevent re-creating them. Ideally, the scripts should include "if does not exist" clause (there is an open issue for that here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1855), but this is not the case.

Comment: Thank you very much , this property config works well . but i don't know how to set the application to create the tables only once in other environments,as this property will prevent creating the tables at all